# The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have below code which we are using in our purge procedure. Till yesterday we had no issues, but suddenly today the job failed with error."The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file"

I am not writing anything during transaction, then why such error, is it due to data.

Should i add index on temp table or use sub select while deleting data instead of join to fix it? We cannot reproduce this in our internal as its only in production.

WHILE @RetryCount <=  3 AND @Success = 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY

```
    -- Remove potential orphan records from various tables related to the .NET instances table
        BEGIN TRAN
        CREATE TABLE #WFEngineQueueCompleteOrphanInstanceTable  
        (
            ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
        )

        -- Locate records in the SXAVWFWorkflowEngineQueueComplete table that have no associated records in the Instances table
        INSERT INTO #WFEngineQueueCompleteOrphanInstanceTable 
            SELECT TOP (@RowsPerRun) InstanceUID 
                FROM SXAVWFWorkflowEngineQueueComplete AS q WITH (nolock)
                WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select 1 from [System.Activities.DurableInstancing].[InstancesTable] as i  with (nolock)
                                    where i.id = q.InstanceUID)
                AND CreatedWhenUTC <  @ChkDate
                AND InstanceUID is not null

        -- Perform the delete
        DELETE q FROM SXAVWFWorkflowEngineQueueComplete q
        JOIN #WFEngineQueueCompleteOrphanInstanceTable t ON t.ID = q.InstanceUID

        -- Drop the temporary table
        DROP TABLE #WFEngineQueueCompleteOrphanInstanceTable

        IF @@ERROR <> 0
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR ('Error purging orphan records from SXAVWFWorkflowEngineQueueComplete', 16, 1)
            ROLLBACK TRAN
            RETURN
        END 
        COMMIT TRAN
```

BEGIN CATCH

```
      SELECT  ERROR_NUMBER() AS [Error Number],
      ERROR_MESSAGE() AS [ErrorMessage];     

      -- Now we check the error number to 
      -- only use retry logic on the errors we 
      -- are able to handle.
      --

      IF ERROR_NUMBER() IN (  1204, -- SqlOutOfLocks
                              1205, -- SqlDeadlockVictim
                              1222, -- SqlLockRequestTimeout
                              3960  -- Snapshot Conflict
                              )
      BEGIN
            SET @RetryCount = @RetryCount + 1  

            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'  --let the blocking transaction finish
      END 
      ELSE    
      BEGIN
            -- If we don't have a handler for current error
            -- then we throw an exception and abort the loop
            THROW;
```

END
    END CATCH

Comment: Is the disk full?

Comment: We have enough space in prod

Comment: i have similar symptoms. if i just execute what is inside TRAN and TRY, it completes successfully. otherwise, i get this error. Disk space is more than enough.